# Pass variable from link to div

Tags: html, yii

I have a pure css3 modal call by a link, and I wish to pass some variable to the modal.

**Modal**

```
    <div id="reasonmodal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="header">
            Reason
        </div>

        <div class="copy">
             //content
        </div>
        <div class="footer"><a href="?r=Register/UpdateReason&appid=">Close</a></div>
        <br />  

    </div>
```

**HTML**

```
    //some other code with foreach appid
    <a href="#reasonmodal">Click</a>
```

I want pass foreach appid to the modal, any suggestion to do that ? Thanks

Comment: Where is AppID coming from? Where is it available?

Comment: @Alexus appid is come from Controller and foreached

Comment: I am confused. Foreach is javascript?

Comment: @Alexus did u know php foreach ? Yii controller ?

Comment: Ah I see. NO sorry I am not familiar with Yii.

Comment: why you didn't put the reasonmodal div inside the foreach ?
The link and div is HTML. The Var you want to pass os PHP.
HTML doesn't have variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have an idea (js only):

```
<a href="#reasonmodal" class="modal-link" rel="<?=$app_id?>" >Click</a>

<a href="#" id="submit-link">Close</a>
```

and modal action :

```
$(".modal-link").click(function(){
   $("#submit-link").attr('href','?r=Register/UpdateReason&appid='+$(this).attr('rel'));
   $($(this).attr('href')).modal('show');
});
```

Comment: YOU ARE AWESOME !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
THIS IS WHAT I ACTUALLY WANT !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
THANKS YOU ! SO AND SO MUCH !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Just print the var

```
<div id="reasonmodal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="header">
            Reason
        </div>

        <div class="copy">
             //content
        </div>
        <div class="footer"><a href="?r=Register/UpdateReason&appid=<?php echo $appid; ?>">Close</a></div>
        <br />  

    </div>
```

Comment: I tired ~ all appid are the same

Answer (score 0):

I see that you want to dynamically pass variables to the model each time click the html div.
Just use ajax post to get these values and update the modal content before it is triggered

Modal

```
<div id="reasonmodal">
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="header">
        Reason
    </div>

    <div class="copy" id="modal_content">
         //content
    </div>
    <div class="footer"><a href="?r=Register/UpdateReason&appid=">Close</a></div>
    <br />  

</div>
```

Add a onclick event to html div

```
<a href="#reasonmodal" onlick='updateModal()'>Click</a>
```

Implement the updateModal() function which will POST an ajax request to get data. Something like this:

```
function viewDetail()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: <?php echo "\"" . Yii::app()->createUrl('controller/action') . "\""; ?>,
        data: { param : "value"},   
    }).done(function(msg){
        //update the model content with msg responded from server
        document.getElementById("modal_content").innerHTML = msg;    
    });     
}
```

The modal will be triggered after the html content is updated.

(Give me a vote-up if it works for you)