# Jquery get different input hidden value to a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I making a context menu and it almost done, just left this problem for me, but i have no idea to do this:

This is the [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jma023yc/)

**Get different value from input hidden to a single link, because I want to pass it into a controller action**

```
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td class="element">im here
            <input type="hidden" id="theid" name="theid" value="1"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="element">im there
            <input type="hidden" id="theid" name="theid" value="2"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="element">im where
            <input type="hidden" id="theid" name="theid" value="3"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div type="context" class="menu"> // link
    <a href="?r=TotheLink/HAHA&theid="><label class="menuitem">Cancel this app</label></a>
</div>
```

I want to pass the value to **`theid`** , for example when right click **im here** the link should get the hidden value = 1 and so on, any suggestion to do that ? Thanks

Comment: firstly, your html is invalid you are using duplicate id's `theid`

Comment: @Kartikeya because i have to pass `theid` so all id should be same

Comment: Your mistaken my friend you are using three hidden fields with same id's which is **absolutely wrong.**

Comment: @Kartikeya then u tell me how to pass different value?

Comment: You may give an id to exactly one element.

Comment: @baao I have a lot of different value

Comment: @The Smile I think this may be a lost cause. You're missing a lot of fundamentals about how to properly write/process HTML and Javascript.

Comment: @TheSmile (in one page) `id` must be unique, if not use `class`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mouse event object contains the target you were clicking on. So you can access that, pass it to jQuery and do whatever you want with it, eg. accessing the ID of the input.

```
$(e.target).find('input').attr('id');
```

And as the other commentators, I'm hoping that your IDs are different ;)

**Edit:** I re-read your question, you just want the value. So you don't need the ID `theid` in your markup overall (for this usecase). Getting the value from the clicked element:

```
$(e.target).find('input').val();
```

And working, see the `alert()`: [See this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jma023yc/1/)

Comment: can u make it in js fiddle ? because i really no idea how to do this , different input id with different value but only one value can set into link.

Comment: did u get what I need ? @@

Comment: thanks , yea it get the correct value but i want to set into link not alert , so i can `$_GET['theid']` from the link it pass

Comment: if I append the link to the correct value is this possible ?

Comment: Take what's inside the alert and append it to the link attribute. Similar to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27145352/4151333

Comment: Hi @Felix , this is the http://jsfiddle.net/ay9wg3o7/ i made , able to read the `theid` but context menu cannot close, did u know where the problem ?

Comment: You're generating `.menu` dynamically, so the function doesn't know it and can't bind the event. Quick fix: Fade out `.tomenu` instead of `.menu`